# Как дать доступ к работе скрипту на заблокированном экране Windows

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Есть программа на C#, шаблон WinForms, самой формы нет, только работа с SendKeys, короче говоря, хочу сделать программу которая может разблокировать ПК с экрана блокировки, с помощью SendKeys он вводит пароль и нажимает Enter, но протестировать не могу из-за того, что запускаю скрипт, блокирую компьютер и тогда скрипт выбивает ошибку что у него не было доступа чтобы выполнить ввод пароля и на нажатие Enter

```
Вызвано исключение: "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception" в System.Windows.Forms.dll
Необработанное исключение типа "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception" в System.Windows.Forms.dll
Отказано в доступе
```

Как можно это пофиксить? пробовал запускать от имени Администратора, не помогло.

Comment: Это нужно написать иммитатор HID (клавиатуры).